# Condition in lambda expression order by

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have 2 Lists that return the same Item .
`<foo>` has the propriety `orderType` that is 0 for the first list and 1 for the second one 
On the first list I do filtering and I have to add the items from the second list to the result that is limited by pagination. 
Basically this is my final Query :

```
var listFoo= QueryList1.Concat(QueryList2);  //(IQueriable)
List<foo> listFoo =listFoo.OrderByDescending(r => r.ID)
                          .ThenBy(d =>d.orderType)
                          .Skip((currentPageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
                          .Take(pageSize)
                          .ToList();
```

This works great because list 1 works as main item and list 2 works as details for first list. Also my filters should work only on the first list. But the problem comes here. How can I order the second list **only** by date. I need to list the details ordered by date. 
Basically i need something like :

```
List<foo> listFoo =listFoo.OrderByDescending(r => r.ID)
                          .ThenBy(d =>d.orderType)
                          .ThenBy(x=>(x.ordertype==1)?x.Date)
                          .Skip((currentPageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
                          .Take(pageSize)
                          .ToList();
```

Edit :

```
List 1 : 
id =1,ordertype=0,Date = new DateTime(1950,1,4),  [0]
id =2,ordertype=0,Date = new DateTime(1950,2,1)   [1]
List 2 :
id =1,ordertype=1,Date = new DateTime(1950,1,5),  [2]
id =1,ordertype=1,Date = new DateTime(1950,1,2),  [3]
id =1,ordertype=1,Date = new DateTime(1950,1,3),  [4]
id =1,ordertype=1,Date = new DateTime(1950,1,4)   [5]

This should be ordered as follows : 
[0],[3],[4],[5],[2],[1]
```

Comment: It seems to me you can always simply order by ID, ordertype and Date. Ordertype 0 will always be first with identical IDs.

Comment: Yes ... you are correct. This is the solution I will use .. I am going to give Stanley the correct answer in case someone bumps on the issue i thought i had. ( the problem was in defining a field) . Cheers mate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the last part of the ternary operator:

```
listFoo = listFoo.OrderByDescending(r => r.ID)
                           .ThenBy(d =>d.orderType)
                           .ThenBy(x => (x.ordertype==1) ? x.Date : DateTime.MinValue)
                           .Skip((currentPageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
                           .Take(pageSize)
                           .ToList();
```

If you don't care about the order if `ordertype` is something other than 1 then the `else` condition is arbitrary.

Comment: this was one of those "this looks crazy enough to work" moments. Tried it with your syntax ... and it didn't work .. But if that syntax is possible its only a matter of time till i get it right. Can you use that syntax within the Order by Lambda Expression ?

Comment: Sure - maybe if you modified your question to outline exactly what the order criteria is (with example data) it would be clear.   Is ID unique?  Is ID the link between the two lists?

Comment: Added Edit : 
Id is not unique it is used to help order the elements from the 2 lists. ordertype makes the element from the first list be on top of the detail elements(list2). Date should order only elements from the second list)

Comment: I fixed two things - `MinDate` should be `MinValue` and you're re-delaring `listFoo` but using it as the source list.  I don't know if those were your issues; if it still doesn't work please explain _how_ it doesn't work.  I've verified the results in LinqPad.

Comment: The prroblem was in my list creation .. I misunderstood the specification.It works great.Thank you